# Docker service health check is not working for spring boot application

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I am running my spring boot web application as docker service and it is running fine without health check.

But when I tried to create docker service with health check options, my service gets restart automatically after some time (maybe after health heck timeout) and it never is stable.

I create `\health` rest endpoint and is simply return ok
Here is command which I am using to create service with health check option and without it.

Command with health check option:

```
sudo docker service create \
    --health-cmd="curl --silent --fail localhost:8090/health || exit 1" \
    --health-interval=5s \
    --health-retries=12 \
    --health-timeout=2s \
    --health-start-period=60s \
    --name=my-service \
    -p "8090:8090" \
    my-docker-img
```

output:

```
s43fbah1qdlxb01s4x5veecos
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: starting  [============================================>      ]
```

Command without health check:

```
sudo docker service create \
    --name=my-service \
    -p "8090:8090" \
    my-docker-img
```

My spring boot application takes 20s to up and running.

Comment: Why did you create your own endpoint and not use the actuator `/health` endpoint? Also if that is on Spring Boot 2.x then the url has changed to `/actuator/health`.

Comment: I am not using the actuator, its simple hello world type application

Comment: Still why not use actuator but invent your own. However not sure why it would fail. If the result is more often then not not OK docker will restart the container. So it might actually be your own endpoint that has the issue.

Comment: Here I specify health check url in health-cmd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that "curl" is installed in the container. 
`--health-cmd="curl --silent --fail localhost:8090/health || exit 1"` might be failing. Everything else looks fine.

The following command will help you in debugging the issue. You will be able to see the log :

```
sudo docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' [container-name-or-id]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. working fine after I install crul in my docker image

Comment: I apologize coming late to the party, but I have very much similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962015/cannot-hit-a-health-check-endpoint-from-dockerized-spring-boot-app)

Comment: @Nitin, how did you manage to install curl in the docker image ?

Comment: It depends on your base docker base image.
try with `apt install -y curl`